# How can I remove all products images for a specific store/website?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

When I import CSV file for products I got every time duplicate products images.
I must import the CSV file every time with products images value for all products there for I got duplicate products images.

Now, I must remove all products images for a specific store/website before import same products with CSV.

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL will remove all images and labels from the database

```
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar
WHERE  attribute_id IN (SELECT attribute_id
                        FROM   `eav_attribute`
                        WHERE  store_id = REPLACE_WITH_STORE_ID and attribute_code IN (
                               'small_image', 
                               'small_image_label',
                               'image',
                               'image_label',
                               'thumbnail',
                               'thumbnail_label' ))
```

Also run the following to remove the images from the server

`rm -rf pub/media/catalog/*`

Comment: It's not working.

Comment: The command at the bottom would also remove category images...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete store specific images you need to run next sql queries:

```
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value WHERE store_id=STORE_ID;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar where attribute_id IN (87,88,89) and row_id = ANY (select row_id from catalog_product_flat_STORE_ID);
UPDATE `catalog_product_flat_STORE_ID` SET `image` = NULL, `small_image` = NULL, `swatch_image` = NULL, `thumbnail` = NULL WHERE `attribute_set_id` = 4;
```

Hope that helps you.

Answer (score -2):

Please try with below query which is remove your primary image.

```
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE  attribute_id IN (87,88,89) AND entity_id='product_id'
```

second query here

```
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery WHERE attribute_id=90 and entity_id='product_id'
```

Note : Please verify attribute_id in **eav_attribute** table like value is base, thumnail, small_image.

Comment: I need it for a specific store.

Comment: please check with 'catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value' this table.

Comment: not only are you hard coding foreign key values from other tables but you're not specifying a reference to the store which is the entire purpose of the question. Terrible answer.